# Global variable sometimes does not update in fbAsyncInit

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this code :-

```
var FB_INIT = false;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.2'
  });
  FB_INIT = true;
};
```

Now, when the user clicks a login button, I check if the FB api has loaded.  For example :-

```
function checkLogin(){
  if (!FB_INIT) {
   alert("Not loaded!");
  }else{
   login();
  }
}
```

But, I face a very confusing problem here. If the user clicks the login button after the api has loaded,  it works fine. But if, by any chance, the user clicks the login button before the api has loaded, he gets the alert box everytime he clicks the login button again **even after the api has loaded**. I checked the `FB_INIT` in Firefox console by printing `console.log(FB_INIT)` in the JS console in the browser itself and I get `false`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add a console output to the fbAsyncInit function itself, to see if that does even get executed in that case.

Comment: @CBroe I tried printing to the console "initialized" in the `fbAsyncInit ` function. Same thing. It gets called only if the user has not clicked the login button before

Comment: So what happens in your `login` function? Probably some call that requires the `FB` object to be instantiated already; and since it isn’t, you get an error …? Probably easiest to bind the event handler to the button inside fbAsyncInit (plus maybe additional style manipulation of the button to have it “grayed out” before and then remove that, or even set to disabled before that.)